# How to write prolog code to find student grade with below data?

Tags: prolog

A student name is represented using a Prolog atom like `jim`.
    A student grade is represented using a Prolog int like 95.
    A grade for a student is represented using the Prolog structure `name_grade(Name, Grade)` where `Name` is a student name and `Grade` is a student grade.

A grade-tree is an ordered binary tree which is one-of the following:

- `[]`::
  Represents the empty tree.
- `tree(name_grade(Name, Grade), TL, TR)`::
  Represents a tree with `Name` a Prolog atom representing a
  student name, `Grade` is a Prolog integer representing a grade and `TL` is a grade-tree containing only names less-than `Name` (using Prolog's binary relation `@<`) and `TR` is a grade-tree containing only names greater-than `Name` (using Prolog's binary relation `@>`).

I am thinking to Write below Prolog's procedures:

- `get_grade(GradeTree, Name, Grade)`::
  Given a grade-tree `GradeTree`, matches `Grade` with the grade stored for name `Name` in `GradeTree`. Fails if there is no match for `Name` in `GradeTree`. Should use the ordering of the tree to minimize the search.
- `add_grade(GradeTree, NameGrade, GradeTreeZ)`::
  Given a grade-tree `GradeTree` and a name-grade `NameGrade` returns `GradeTreeZ` as `GradeTree` with `NameGrade` added, respecting the ordering relation among the nodes in the grade-tree. Note that if there was a previous node in `GradeTree` with the same name as in
  `NameGrade`, then it is replaced by one containing the same grade as in `NameGrade`.

Example log:

```
?- add_grade([], name_grade(jim, 95), T1),
| add_grade(T1, name_grade(tom, 90), T2),
| get_grade(T2, tom, Grade).

T1 = tree(name_grade(jim, 95), [], [])
T2 = tree(name_grade(jim, 95), [], tree(name_grade(tom, 90), [], []))
Grade = 90 ;
false.

?- add_grade([], name_grade(tom, 90), T1),
| add_grade(T1, name_grade(tom, 85), T2),
| get_grade(T2, tom, Grade).

T1 = tree(name_grade(tom, 90), [], [])
T2 = tree(name_grade(tom, 85), [], [])
Grade = 85 ;
false.

?- add_grade([], name_grade(tom, 90), T1),
| add_grade(T1, name_grade(bill, 85), T2),
| get_grade(T2, ann, G).
false.
```

Comment: dumping your homework assignment here with minimal alterations is not how it's supposed to work. try writing some code of your own, post it and any error messages/wrong output you get, and then ask a specific question please. :)

Comment: The title asks how to represent the information, but the answer to that question is already given. Is there another question?